# Joda Time daysBetween() returns string prefix "P" and suffix "D"

Tags: datetime, jodatime, days

I am using Joda Time to get daysBetween() two days, but it's returning no of days between 2 days and the prefix and suffix of the data is adding "P" & "D" for days between and "P" & "Y" for years between the same will be in monthsBetween(), yearsBetween(), hoursBetween(), minutesBetween() and secondsBetween().

how to get data without prefix and suffix string?

```
DateTime start = new DateTime(2004, 12, 25, 0, 0, 0, 0);
DateTime end = new DateTime(2006, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);

// able to calculate whole days between two dates easily
Days days = Days.daysBetween(start, end);

// able to calculate whole months between two dates easily
Months months = Months.monthsBetween(start, end);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The prefix/suffix is only the string representation of the durations, which is based on ISO8601 as explained in the `toString` javadoc of these classes.

If you just want the number of days, you can use:

```
int days = Days.daysBetween(start, end).getDays();
```

Similarly, `Months` has a `getMonths` method.